# How to restrict grep to search only below a token of a column?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

How can I use grep to search only the values of a column below a token? For example in the following CSV file:

```
A     B     C  
1     4     5  
2     3     0  
1     3     6
```

...how can I get only the values of column B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure you can do this with grep, however you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $2}' file.csv
```

It will print out the second column of your file.

---

**EDIT**

If you do not want to print the column name out (`B` in the example), you can set a condition on FNR:

> FNR         The input record number in the current input file.

Like this:

```
awk ' FNR > 1 { print $2}' file.csv
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If your file is a real CSV (Comma separated values) file, you have to provide the field separator argument (`-F` or `--field-separator`):

```
awk -F',' ' FNR > 1 { print $2}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Using grep in the command as per the question.

```
cat file.csv | cut -d " " -f 2 | grep -o '[0-9]'
```

Where cut -d (delimiter is " ") using blankspace
or "," when csv is comma
and -f 2 is second field

grep -o is --only-matching

Edit to allow for non numeric field loses grep

```
cat file.csv | cut -d " " -f2 | tail -n +2
```